# Alfresco share dashlet : how to set componentId unique for all users

Tags: alfresco

i am trying to set a unique id for component Id property  so any user can access the same dashlet information, like the resizer and other fields.
I already tried to set manually the component Id, but when i do that i cant even save properties from the same user.

[image]
the dashlet js.  well.get.js

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

the freemaker template
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNhML.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "componentId : instance.object.id," instead of "componentId : objectId," ?

Comment: yes , the previous stored  instance.object.id in this variable objectId.

Comment: When using instance.object.id (not a static object id), for the user(s) you're testing with, are they admin users?  Do they see the edit icon?   For those that can see the edit icon, are they able to resize the dashlet?

Comment: the admin can see the edit button on the toolbar of the dashlet, and other users cant. but thats not the point i asking here... i want to save the component properties for both. for example if the admin edit an content, or resize the dashlet any other user can see that change.   like what happens with the site notice dashlet

Comment: I see.  Are you sure you're editing and viewing the same instance of the dashlet between users?

Comment: no, their are not, each user got his own instance.... but i want to make the same. how can i make it have the same instance?

Comment: If you remove and add the custom dashlet, does it create an instance that reflect change across the user base?

Comment: no it does not reflect the changes made by other user.